# How do I rewrite this conditional with an option in Scala in a cleaner way?

Tags: scala, dictionary, conditional-statements, scala-option

Is there a cleaner way of writing this in scala?

```
def myFunction(somethingA: String, somethingB: Option[String]): Unit =
  if (somethingB.isDefined) 
    foo("somethingA" -> somethingA, "somethingB" -> somethingB.get) 
  else
    foo("somethingA" -> somethingA)
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
def myFunction(somethingA: String, somethingB: Option[String]): Unit =
  foo("somethingA" -> somethingA, somethingB.map("somethingB" -> _).getOrElse(.... pleh ....))
```

But even if I replace the ".... pleh ...." part with some kind of expression, i don't want it to even add the mapping if somethingB isn't defined. So I don't envision that remotely working. Not sure what the right solution is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much cleaner:

```
def myFunction(somethingA: String, somethingB: Option[String]): Unit = somethingB match {
  case Some(b) => foo("somethingA" -> somethingA, "somethingB" -> b)
  case None    => foo("somethingA" -> somethingA)
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Was trying to envisage some sort of `flatMap` based option but couldn't quite work it out. +1

Comment: Yeah that's about as clean as it gets I guess.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what `foo` is, but given

```
scala> def foo(ps: (String, String)*) = ps.size
foo: (ps: (String, String)*)Int
```

then

```
scala> def myFunction(somethingA: String, somethingB: Option[String]): Int =
     | foo(List(Some("A"->somethingA), somethingB.map("B"->_)).flatten: _*)
myFunction: (somethingA: String, somethingB: Option[String])Int
```

may be what you intend.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try folding the `Option` if you are using Scala 2.10:

```
val result = somethingB.fold(foo("somethingA" -> somethingA))(b => foo("somethingA" -> somethingA, "somethingB" -> b))
```

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
val a = "somethingA" -> somethingA

somethingB.map{ b =>
   foo(a, "somethingB" -> b) 
}.getOrElse { foo(a) }
```

Hardly more readable. Btw. I don't think you can change the call binding depending on a value :(